# Return to the intital position of the array

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

The title is in the last position of arrray because of for loop but i want the array to be in 1st position after the for loop ends

```
@foreach($title as $title)
<li><a href="{{url('page/'.$title->slug)}}">{{$title->slug}}</a></li>
@endforeach
<li><a href="{{ route('front.end',['slug'=>$title->slug])}}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>FrontEnd</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this way

```
<?php $i=0; $first_slug="";?>
@foreach($all_title as $title)
  <?php 
    if($i == 0)
    {
      $first_slug = $title->slug;
    }
    $i++;
  ?>
  <li><a href="{{url('page/'.$title->slug)}}">{{$title->slug}}</a></li>
@endforeach
<li><a href="{{ route('front.end',['slug'=>$first_slug])}}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>FrontEnd</a></li>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: all_title (View:

Comment: thanks worked on mine just changed all _title as title and worked perfectly on mine